# Где в вордпрессе записан bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )

Tags: wordpress

Надо изменить значение  `bloginfo ('stylesheet_url')` для переопределения папки стилей.

Где это значение записано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bloginfo ('stylesheet_uri')` возвращает ссылку на файл стилей текущей темы в виде

```
http://site.org/wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/style.css
```

Вы можете переопределить этот вывод с помощью фильтра

```
add_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', 'filter_stylesheet_uri' );
function filter_stylesheet_uri( $stylesheet_uri, $stylesheet_dir_uri ) {
    $uri = ... // ваш код
    return $uri;
}
```

Но как это будет работать в вашем случае - неизвестно. Многие темы и плагины используют `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` для обращения к файлам темы.

И да, прямой ответ на ваш вопрос: где записано. В базе, конечно. В таблице `wp_options` есть запись с `option_name=stylesheet`.